# How can I improve performance of UTF32 to UTF16 surrogate pair converter

Tags: javascript, performance, unicode

I am using following converter to do the splits of Unicode chars not in 'normal' plane.

```
function toUTF16Pair(x) {
        var first = Math.floor((x - 0x10000) / 0x400) + 0xD800;
        var second = ((x - 0x10000) % 0x400) + 0xDC00;
        return '\\u'+first.toString(16) + '\\u'+second.toString(16);
}
```

I am looking for performance improvement (if one is possible).

Comment: Have you considered iterating, creating an array of the new characters/code points, and joining them right at the end? Since JS strings are immutable, that might be faster.

Comment: @ssube they are within a pile of 'normal' unicodes I suppose in those cases where I do have a chain it might be worth it but I still would read them first to identify that they are the UTF32 ones.

Comment: I would convert your replace call into a `hex.forEach` type loop and pass "good" code points through untouched, but when you run into a point that will end up as a pair, return the pair instead. Take the results and `join` them once.

Comment: Please show us how you are calling this function.

Comment: @Bergi Hi Bergi, it can be different, usually some jquery select `.text()` split on `;` or it can be `symbol.getCharCodeAt(0).toString(16)`. The check `if (x >= 0x10000 && x <= 0x10FFFF)` is outside the function and it wouldn't be called if character is out. I think I will narrow question to only actual algorithm bit, and will remove check and replace to that clean hex code comes in, cause other bits can be looked at separately really.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius: So you are basically looping over a relatively short string?

Comment: @Bergi no, it usually is whole parsed page, or parts of it or it could be data from text-areas.

Comment: So how do you read in that data as UTF32? I guess that's the part where performance could be improved the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual did it myself with some binary magic. Please try to beat this.

```
function toUTF16Pair(x) {
    return '\\u' + ((((x - 0x10000) >> 0x0a) | 0x0) + 0xD800).toString(16) 
         + '\\u' + (((x - 0x10000) & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00).toString(16)
}
```

In case anyone is wondering how it works:
`>> 0x0a` - is binary right shift 10 positions that is equivalent to division by 1024.
`| 0x0` - is equivalent of `Math.floor`
`& 0x3FF` - because modulo of 2 can be expressed as (`x % n == x & (n - 1)`) which in my case is `& 1063` in decimal.

Hope this saves you some time.