# How is Unicode (UTF-16) data that is out of collation stored in varchar column?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, encoding, collation, varchar

This is purely theoretical question to wrap my head around

Let's say I have `Unicode` cyclone ( `1F300`) symbol. If I try to store it in `varchar` column that has default `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation, cyclone symbol cannot not fit into one byte that is used per symbol in `varchar`...

The ways I can see this done:

1. Like javascript does for symbols out of Basic plane([BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode))) where it stores them as 2 symbols (surrogate pairs), and then additional processing is needed to [put them back together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596239/how-can-i-improve-performance-of-utf32-to-utf16-surrogate-pair-converter/37674792#answer-37674792)...
2. Just truncate the symbol, store first byte and drop the second.... (data is toast - you should have read the manual....)
3. Data is destroyed and nothing of use is saved... (data is toast - you should have read the manual....)
4. Some other option that is outside of my mental capacity.....

I have done some research after inserting couple of different unicode symbols

```
 INSERT INTO [Table] (Field1)
 VALUES ('')

 INSERT INTO [Table] (Field1)
 VALUES ('')
```

and then reading them as bytes `SELECT 
cast (field1 as varbinary(10))`  in both cases I got `0x3F3F`.

[image]

`3F` in `ascii` is `?` ([question mark](http://ascii.cl/)) e.g two question marks (`??`) that I also see when doing normal `select *` does that mean that data is toast and not even 1st bite is being stored?

**How is Unicode data that is out of collation stored in varchar column?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is toast and is exactly what you see, 2 x 0x3F bytes. This happens during the type conversion prior to the insert and is effectively the same as `cast('' as varbinary(2))` which is also 0xF3F3 (as opposed to casting `N''`).

> When Unicode data must be inserted into non-Unicode columns, the columns are internally converted from Unicode by using the WideCharToMultiByte API and the code page associated with the collation. If a character cannot be represented on the given code page, the character is replaced by a question mark (?) [Ref](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962(v=sql.90).aspx#code-snippet-1).

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the answer. I wonder why two `??` instead of 1 `?`, feels like an insult to injury, lol...

Answer (score 1):

Yes the data has gone.

[Varchar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) requires less space, compared to [NVarchar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186939.aspx).  But that reduction comes at a cost.  There is no space for a Varchar to store Unicode characters (at 1 byte per character the internal lookup just isn't big enough).

From [Microsoft's Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> ...consider using the Unicode nchar or nvarchar data types to minimize character conversion issues.

As you've spotted, unsupported characters are repalced with question marks.

Comment: It's not the size that's the issue; It's the definition and behavior of the type, particularly implicit conversions. nchar is one UTF-16 code unit; Some Unicode codepoints require one, some two. Some database systems can store as Unicode as UTF-8, where a codepoint requires one, two, three or four 8-bit code units.